# Should an on-topic edit that links to a personal page/library be approved?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, edits

I was served this review task in the suggested edit review queue

[image: Edit Review]

This is the (now closed and deleted) original question:

> ## Is there any Hijri Date library in Ruby?
>
> Is there any Hijri Date library in Ruby?
>
> #### Update:
>
> Here is a list of hijri gems out there:
>
> - https://github.com/TheEmpty/Hijri-Gem
> - https://github.com/mygulamali/hijri_date
> - https://github.com/moh-alsheikh/hijri_ummalqura
> - https://github.com/ecleel/hijri
>
> <sub>https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3569827/is-there-any-hijri-date-library-in-ruby</sub>

I think the [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/14383691) is valid, but should it be an edit to the question?

Perhaps it should have been an answer or a comment, but the asker *is* linking to hijri gems.

The reason I'm on the fence about this is because the repo doesn't seem very popular.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

That edit is bogus, the question is bogus, it should all be closed and deleted.

I have voted to close the question as "Request for off-site resource", and rejected the edit as no improvement whatsoever.

Answer (score 14):

Editing in one's own project is always risky, however well intended it may be.

In this case, the link was added to a question. Which makes the edit wrong. The question is where the asker shows what they found themselves, while doing the research. So, this edit puts words into the OP's mouth.
The edit should have been rejected. The reviewers who approved this edit should have been more careful.

Apart from this, as @Tiny Giant points out in their own [answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/338355/812149), the question itself is textbook off-topic.

If the question had been on-topic, this would have been appropriate as a comment, provided the purpose is to help the OP and not to spamvertize one's own handiwork.
The editor is not a frequent editor and it looks like they have not advertised their project elsewhere on the site. So, even though the edit itself should have been rejected, I believe the editor was acting in good faith.